# Sunrise time calculation doesn't match Google's result

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I am not sure if it really is related to Android, but since I am going to use it for an Android app, I am tagging Android too.

I am trying to build some logic to calculate sunrise time if lat-long are given.

I've tried following, but everything gives a slightly different time of the Sunrise of the location I provide it with (of Bangalore, India), and when I search for google with the keyword `Bangalore Sunrise` Google gives a different result in the card which looks more accurate:

- Tried porting this C code to Java : http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/code/sunrise.c.html
- Tried using this formula from WikiPedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation
- Tried using this library : https://github.com/mikereedell/sunrisesunsetlib-java
- Tried using this Web Service : http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#sun

All give different results, and still Google's looks to be more acccurate.

Does anybody here know of an API or a better calculation for this? Or the algorithm/webservice that Google is using for their cards?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How large is the difference?  "Bangalore" isn't a precise lat/long, it's a range of them.  At about 12° 58′, the terminator moves west at about 1600KPH - fast enough to make you wrong quickly if you're using a different longitude than Google is.

Comment: The average difference is about 30 mins. If I search google for `Bangalore lat long` it gives me the lat-long, and I use the same values in the calculation, assuming that they're also using the same.

Comment: Please give me the android implemetation as soon as possible.. Its a task for me. please

Comment: How much are you willing to pay me for the implementation? :)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't studied all the links you gave, but most likely the differences stem from different assumptions & definitions.  In particular, the following factors tend to vary from algorithm to algorithm:

- Atmospheric refraction included or not (i.e. "true" or "apparent" elevation)
- "Top" or "center" of sun breaking horizon

There are certainly other factors as well, and the problem becomes increasingly ill-defined as latitude gets farther from the equator.  But these factors alone can account for minutes of difference.

Comment: Agreed. And I assume that the sunrise is pretty relative, as there are multiple events related to the light coming up after the night. Still, if somebody goes up to verify their current city's sunrise time, they land up on Google as the first place, and if there are huge differences between it and my app's calculation, that's going to leave a bad impression.

Answer (score 3):

Indian standard time is  UTC+05:30, that's probably why you are seeing a 30 min difference.

The algorithm can calculate sunrise time in UTC, but it won't be able to convert UTC to local time, which requires complicated timezone knowledge. The algorithm probably does something very simplistic, like

```
localTime = utcTime + 1_hour * longitude / 15_degree
```

which is 5 hours for city of Banglore.

You should take the UTC time, then convert it to local time by using Java date APIs.

Comment: Those calculations ask me the lat-long, so I am supposing they're taking the time difference in account?

Comment: the algorithm can calculate sunrise time in UTC, but it won't be able to convert UTC to local time, which requires complicated timezone knowledge. the algorithm probably simply adds `1hour * longitude/15`, which is 5 hours for Banglore. that's too simplistic.

Comment: Oh thanks. btw, which algorithm are you referring to? anyone from the link I posted in the question? It would help me to narrow it down.

Comment: I assume all of them have this problem.

Comment: Okay, let me check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A quick search lead me to this api

http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#sun

Comment: Oh yes, I have already tried it. Quite a lot of difference from what Google or Weather.com says. Have this link in my question too. I was wanting to calculate it offline only